# flow: function type using ExtractReturn

Tags: redux, flowtype, boilerplate

I'm trying to reduce boilerplate of `redux` code typed with `flow`.

In particular, I want to avoid defining `action types` manually, but let `flow` deduce them from `typed action creators`, using the `ExtractReturn` tricks (as described for example in [Shane Osbourne post](https://hackernoon.com/redux-flow-type-getting-the-maximum-benefit-from-the-fewest-key-strokes-5c006c54ec87) or [Martin Hochel post](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/redux-typescript-typed-actions-with-less-keystrokes-d984063901d)):

```
type _ExtractReturn<B, F: (...args: any[]) => B> = B;
type ExtractReturn<F> = _ExtractReturn<*, F>;
```

But it does not catch simple error, for example it should catch that `action.id` is a `number` and not a `string`: [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AfQKIAeKATgIYDGKASligK4kB2APAEIA0oAYgFygAKAHQiyJAOYBnfmSZoA2gF0AlKAC8APlBsta7QG5UmHEVKUadRq2668p8lVoNmLAFRcbhxBVhNJKUHE6dUEASwATfiZ6AFsAIywSVU1BAG9QdGx+AHIAcXwAFWyuCNAAX2VDHz8A8KxoEIEIqNiEpPUtAXTMrByAEXwAGWLQUoqq339QSWC9JsjQaPjErgA3Mmh6XunSUKZxZM7u4xyAZUKRiLWNrfLK5B7QAEEqUN91RFBQAB9Qe3MnFYWD1YJBAnQNJ8fgAC-6OSwuEFgmYoSFfX5wizOVhI0B1aAaLyQehMV7vEhYcL0CiJATmN5MfgvFAM1SpKFfSTwUIoCgAC0E9N8Qh6bI5XwlFDIM1AeQu-HZEqVyuqUyYsEk1IFeiFTCE6s1-P0XxAfxIJFgJFAUt5fMp4uVEriFLIAGtDI6vmUHZLpThsucigqfY7VQFmjsSHtxCFdUIIsbQKb8ObLaBXOqUK5rWRbfbPcrnVg3R7Pd6C1KZdkBsNgwWlUWSyHyuLvWUgA).

If the action were defined "manually", error would be catched: [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqA5gKa4C8oAFAJYAmAXKOgK4C2ARgQE4CUoxAfOQG9Q2AJ4AHAnQDkAcQCiAFSkAaUNVABfTgG5UGHKCoFoPctTqNWHbn0HDxk0FIAicgDIq1VTTr1ZcmESmlLT0zGzsqgBuAIbQDI447BToeDb8ZEKiEtIAyoqe1NFxCT66iNkE+EQAgijYFBimApXS8kqq5mFW7Bq6laCB2HUNTaQtDnkFnaGWEcXxidjJqX0VDobGI43oza1Orh4zFuEca+sSoNtj1cP1O6AAPoO1903PRtDX6OWQDOhvXbsAhUBgoDhkGKAujfbgCRCgRGDeAUbAoAAW5Cho3QADpKnCEUjiSgYoEnO0pHR4cTaUi0P56LBMGDMaRsTtcehmaztIiQKA5Ox2LB2KBSWj0SCiXTiSxgTEANa6WWaGW00nkqT5JTU9WqhkGLpJFJ4UwcjC46h80ACoUisUSjHS1VyhXK-VIjSexGaqoudxU0A012I+UEJUq2Xe4ne71AA).

How can I have all errors properly catched in the `reducer` function, without writing manually boilerplate code?

- **Edit**: fixed the **Try flow** links.
- **Edit**: I didn't noticed that `Shane Osbourne post` provides a `Flow Try` that seems to work. Looking at it. Actually, it has the same problem. Trying on write a comment on the post to signal it. See comment [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9ffb548a38b6c24114d4bad360bfe8f8)

Comment: Your `Flow Try` is being caught since 0.72 version

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, I managed to get Flow to catch the error that your example didn't catch. [Here is the code](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AfQKIAeKATgIYDGKASligK4kB2APAEIA0oAYgFygAKAHQiyJAOYBnfmSZoA2gF0AlKAC8APlBsta7QG5UmHEVKUadRq2668p8lVoNmLAFRcbhxBVhNJKUHE6dUEASwATfiZ6AFsAIywSVU1BAG9QdGx+AHIAcXwAFWyuCP4I0ABfZUMfPwDwrGgQgVLQaPjE5K0BdMysHIARfAAZYtByqprff1BJYL0WyLbYhJIuADcyaHp+2dJQpnEutIzjHIBlQrGIja2dyurkYFdeXm9pgNxcIIC9H4EAIyPWozL4NJp6cGA4EfPC4Oa-WZ0QFcbIoLD+A7ibKPVzAZB9UAAQSooV86kQoFAAB9TthYJA4T9KTSAAV9Blw8Es2kcxlfBFeSD0Jik8kkLDhegURICcxkpj8EkoBWqVIsqmSeChFAUAAWgnlviEfTVGqpFooZDmoDyV346otTudIICTFgkmlBr0RqYQndnv1+ipIFA+BIJFgJFAVt1esl5udFriErIAGtDEmqRVE5brThspcig7c0nXeMlv4SFiQr6hBFg6BQ+HI9HXO6UK4Y2Q4wms86U1h05mszn+1abdkhqMS-2nYPh6XKuacxUgA).

It's no doubt hacky. I got the idea from [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4002).

Apart from that, I can't offer much more insight. I myself am looking for better solution.

**Edit:** After digging some more, I found that the `$Call` utility type can help a bit:

```
type Action =
  | $Call<typeof get, number>
  | $Call<typeof del, number>
  | $Call<typeof set, number, string>
```

After this, perhaps it's worth abstracting the `$Call<...>` pattern into a parametric type of its own. My knowledge of Flow at this point in time is limited, though, so my few attempts have not been fruitful.

[Here is the full refactor](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqA5gKa4C8oAFAJYAmAXKOgK4C2ARgQE4CUoxAfOQG9Q2AJ4AHAnQDkAcQCiAFSkAaUNTrVQAX04BuVBhygqBaD3Lr6zNlx78yQ0ROkAROQBkVaqtr0GsuJhE5pS0VqwcqgBuAIbQDJKgOOwU6HjcfILC4olSAMqKXtTRcQm++ohOBKAAgijYFBg8iKCgAD6gACQAwnHQADxVsJD4RKqMEey8Le0ABT19gznDxqbj1hzTrR0L0ANDI0HY65Oqyal4vBWQDOj1jeig7ARUDCgcZDH3GHR1DRjcAQzVqYeAUbAoAAW5C+-3QADoqoDga1USgYkFQLJCnQgaj8QS0AF6LBMG9oaRYQ94ehSeTdK0QKA5Ox2LB2KB0RDIS8UQTUSxnjEANb6fmtLR8tEY6r5HGgPHi-FEoyWc5pcxUjDw6gM0BMllsjkAKlp2GNnJi3N5SvxgoIIrF4slSvRmKkbk8uKl-Ptjp92hRkq0QA).